Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab
what should I do with the fstab, when I use a bind on a mounted device?
/etc/fstab:
UUID=1b8076d1-fe24-4027-b182-2a888bb367a7 /opt/wazuh-Logs ext4 defaults 0 0 
/var/ossec/logs /opt/wazuh-Logs none bind,x-systemd.requires=/opt/wazuh-Logs

When I run systemctl daemon-reload I get this error:

[ 1304.458685] systemd-fstab-generator[5603]: Failed to create unit file '/run/systemd/generator/opt-wazuh\x2dLogs.mount', as it already exists. Duplicate entry in '/etc/fstab'?


The source and target are inverted on the bind entry. Try this instead:
UUID=1b8076d1-fe24-4027-b182-2a888bb367a7 /opt/wazuh-Logs ext4 defaults 0 0 
/opt/wazuh-Logs /var/ossec/logs none bind,x-systemd.requires=/opt/wazuh-Logs

